# How to rebase and lock commit on gerrit?

Tags: gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I am working on merge bot that fetch numerous patches and run jenkins job on it.
After fetch I need a way to rebase and lock the commit for uploading new patches. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Could provide an example of what you have done so far and the failure (if so), please? Will your bot push the modifications to some branch or only trigger jenkins jobs?

Comment: @EnriqueS.Filiage the question doesn't refers to what I did, In general I am looking for way to prevent uploading new patches for commit that currently involved in merge bot process